# Win32Api Window Menu Activating issue

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui, win32-process

Running my program it runs and due to me having a menu with EXIT to Destroy the window it runs and immediately exits the window. Unsure how to fix my issue here on compiling the program to have it not run the WindowProcedure function and passing the argument EXITMENU resulting in the Window being destroyed.

***.CPP**

```
#include <windows.h>
#define HELPMENU 1
#define HIGHSCROREMENU 2
#define EXITMENU 3

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 }; // WNDCLASSW is a structure
    LPCWSTR title = L"Window"; // Long Pointer Constant Wide (UTF-16) String 

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW; // Background
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND); // Sets Cursor
    wc.hInstance = hInst; // Instance of window
    wc.lpszClassName = L"windowClass"; // Class name
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure; // Pointer to the function // Controller of window handle

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc)) { // Registers the window class
        return -1;
    }

    //                                                   | binary combination value, posX, posY, Width, Height

    // Creates the window
    CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 100, 100, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    MSG msg = { 0 };


    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0) { // Keeps the window running
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Event Paths */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE: // On window creation
        AddControls(hWnd);
        AddMenu(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // Left Mouse button
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: // Makes GetMessage Function return false, closing the window
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case EXITMENU:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd); // This part of the code shouldn't run on creation
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}

/* Creates menu */
void AddMenu(HWND hWnd) {
    hMenu = CreateMenu(); // Creates menu object
    // AppendMenu(Menu Instance, Usage Type, Argument, String info);
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, HELPMENU, L"Help - F1");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, HIGHSCROREMENU, L"Highscores - F2"); // Menu Created
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, EXITMENU, L"Exit - ESC");
    // SetMenu(Window Handle , Menu Instance);
    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu); // Sets menu for window // 
}
```

Comment: `#define EXITMENU 3` Why? `3` is `WM_MOVE` defined in winuser.h.

Comment: EXITMENU is not a message.  Happens to match WM_MOVE, not a good reason to destroy the window.  Use WM_COMMAND to detect menu commands.

Comment: Thank you dxiv and @Hans Passant, Didn't Realize that it was overriding a defined value already. I'll look at doing the WM_COMMAND instead. Still trying to understand Win32Api as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling the menu commands correctly in your `WindowProcedure()`.

You have defined `EXITMENU` as 3, which is the same value as the `WM_MOVE` message.  So, in your `switch`, you are destroying your window as soon as it receives a `WM_MOVE` message during window creation.

You need to instead handle the menu commands via the `WM_COMMAND` message, per the documentation:

[About Menus: Messages Used With Menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus#messages-used-with-menus)

> When the user chooses a command item from a menu, the system sends a `WM_COMMAND` message to the window procedure. The low-order word of the `WM_COMMAND` message's `wParam` parameter contains the identifier of the chosen item. The window procedure should examine the identifier and process the message accordingly.

Try this instead:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch (msg) {
        ...
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wp) {
                case HELPMENU: {
                    ...
                    return 0;
                }
                case HIGHSCROREMENU: {
                    ...
                    return 0;
                }
                case EXITMENU: {
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        ...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** That being said, consider having your `EXITMENU` handler use `SendMessage(WM_CLOSE)` instead of `DestroyWindow()`.  If your app maintains data that should be saved when the app is closed by the user, you can add a `WM_CLOSE` handler to perform that action regardless of *how* the window is being closed (your exit menu, `X` close button, <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd>, etc).  `DefWindowProc()` destroys a window when processing `WM_CLOSE`.

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch (msg) {
        ...
        case WM_CLOSE: {
            if (data has been modified) {
                prompt user to save data...
                if (cancelled) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (should save) {
                    save data ...
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wp) {
                ...
                case EXITMENU: {
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        ...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I just did thanks to yourself and @Hans Passant.

Comment: Related: [Why do dialog editors start assigning control IDs with 100?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041214-00/?p=37013)